# a problem of probability with an integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I have to determine the value of the constant C to let a function to be 
a probability density.

The function is

$g_3(x)=C x^{-( \lambda +1)}* 1_{[x>r]}(x) $

with $ \lambda, r >0  $

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_3(x)\, dx=  \int_{r}^{\infty} C x^{-( \lambda +1)}(x)  dx= \frac{-c}{\lambda}*[x^{- \lambda}]_{r}^{\infty}= \frac{-c}{\lambda}*[\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } x^{- \lambda }- r^{- \lambda } ]=\frac{-c}{\lambda}*[1- r^{- \lambda } ] $$
but in the suggested solution $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } x^{- \lambda }=1$ and the final result is $\frac{c}{\lambda}*r^{- \lambda } $

Comment:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } x^{- \lambda }= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0 } y^{ \lambda }=1$

Comment: How did you find that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-\lambda}=1}$ when $\lambda>0$? The limit is of course $0$, and you have then to choose $C=\lambda r^\lambda$ so that $g_3$ is a probability density function.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut   $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } x^{- \lambda }= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0 } y^{ \lambda }=1$

Comment: And you are still wrong after the edit. This limit is $0$. Try the limit with $\lambda=1$ for instance: the result should then be obvious. As a side note, the CDF of this density is $P(X\leq x)=1-(\frac{r}{x})^\lambda$, for $x\geq r$. This is a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

Comment: I've got it , thank you